# How to avoid rowwise when comparing a column against a list in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

For example, if I want to count how many elements in a list is smaller than the value in a column, I would do:

```
normvec <- rnorm(20)
df <- data.frame(x=abs(rnorm(50)),col1=1:50) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(nsmaller = sum(normvec <= x)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Is there any way to achieve this without using rowwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working in the `tidyverse` you could also use the `map_*` functions from `purrr`:

```
df |>
  mutate(nsmaller = purrr::map_dbl(x, ~ sum(normvec <= .x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is create a user defined function:

```
compare_with <- function(x){
  sapply(x,\(x) sum(normvec <= x))
}

data.frame(x=abs(rnorm(50)),col1=1:50) %>%
  mutate(nsmaller = compare_with(x))

            x col1 nsmaller
1  0.97252086    1       16
2  0.17686735    2       12
3  0.18464965    3       12
4  0.77039153    4       14
5  0.39934175    5       12
6  1.70049827    6       20
```

As @DarrenTsei mentioned, the core piece is `sapply()`. Therefore, the following works:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(nsmaller = sapply(x, \(y) sum(normvec <= y)))
```